# UIView Follows UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to make an app which has similar functionality to Apple's App Store Today Article controller. Basically, as you can see on the sample gif below the scroll view's content is below the header image. So I am trying to figure out how to make the image follow the scrollView below it, without being added to the scroll view itself? Is there a simple way of bonding image to scroll view? Thanks!

https://gph.is/2LKWBBZ

Comment: The image is also in the scrollView. Please read about `UIScrollView` and also don't look at things on the screen like a user. Look at it like a programmer. You should be seeing a 'UIScrollView` with an `UIImageView` and `UILabel` in the least.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood what's your requirement, do you want to let the image to be scrolled (as shown in the gif image) or you do want to let its y axis to be fixed?

Comment: @AhmadF I want it to be exactly as in the gif

Comment: The simplest way that I could think of is creating it as a *collection view* which contains the header (as the image view) and cell(s) for the other content...

Answer (score 0):

The image on the top could act as the header of the tableView or collectionView that would automatically scroll when you interact with the [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview) / [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview).

You could start looking at [ParallaxTableViewHeader](https://github.com/Vinodh-G/ParallaxTableViewHeader) and [CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout) to see how it works. Note: above controls use this header with UITableView or UICollectionView, but you could do the same with the scrollView with or without any modifications.